# How to Manage multiple shared libraries for jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins

I know how to use the jenkins shared libraries But the problem is we have a large number of libraries with multiple repositories, My question is to easily read those and navigate through those libraries.

Are there any tools or some IDE extension to navigate through these files and methods?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such IDE. jenkins library its groovy/java code

you can use idea or vscode or any other and use global search/Search Everywhere to find files/methods